# How to integrate C program to minimal os using busybox

Tags: boot, grub2, busybox, bios

I am building minimal operating system using busybox. So I want to add my program in my operating system, so I can boot that program from BIOS. So how can I integrate aleast "Hello World" program with minimal operating system. I am using busybox on Ubuntu LTS 22.04.
This files I have generated.
[image]

Comment: Hi Abhishek, welcome to stack overflow. You need to compile the program from source for the architecture of the os

Comment: Unclear what you're asking - do you want to run a binary? A script containing `echo Hello World` ?

Comment: @Panki I want to run hello world from bios

Answer (score 1):

Link against `musl`/`libc` statically, pass the binary as an init, e.g. `init=/path/mybinary`